# Why specifically is having many user generated tables a bad idea

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have a situation where there are many different structured data sets (10s of thousands) with relatively small number of rows (100-10,000) and columns (10-100).  Each of these data sets would only be accessed one at a time.  I don't know the exact columns before hand.

For those who are curious about the business problem that creates the above circumstances.  Each client will input a totally custom dataset.  The data set will then be analysed and output returned.  As new data is put in analysis is redone.  The columns are almost completely different for every client.  Analysis is a some medium heavy stats stuff.

It seems the correct solution would be something like this:
NoSql the client data.  Store metadata about what kind of data the client stores in a relational context. Pull the nosql data and the analysis on adding more data.

And yet in attempting to give myself hard facts as to why creating lots of tables would be a bad idea I have yet to come up with a satisfactory answer.

Performance

As far as I know creating a table is relatively fast, as is altering a table with 100-10,000 rows. I looked up some benchmarks all seemed very reasonable.  Accessing the data will also be comparable to nosql since I'm only looking at one table at a time and not all at once.

Managing the mess

I know that at least with postgres table meta data is stored in tables.  Indicating to me that managing a mess of tables is possible with the use of table metadata.  In a NoSql world I would similarly be managing the mess with metadata.

Table naming is another area of possible messiness but if I look to the world of Redis namespaces I see decent solutions for managing lots of names.

I would love to know specific examples of why this is a terrible idea.  Performance, management, dev time, etc etc.

Comment: Why not go NoSQL with Postgres and use `hstore` or JSON? If you explain us what your *real* problem is, maybe we can come up with a (better) solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried to make the description clearer.  Also I wanted to highlight that I am curious about why not many tables as opposed to what is a more normal solution.

Comment: Using 10s of thousands of tables almost always indicates a bad design. Therefor I asked for the *real* problem you are trying to solve. Rather than focusing on a technical *solution* that you *think* solves your problem it's usually better to discuss the underlying *real* business requirement and see if there is a better or different (technical) solution to that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added some more details of the business case as well as some more details of my thought process.  I appreciate your patience hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: Can't you abstract the data into something that fits a pre-defined schema? Even EAV storage would be an option, or the mentioned hstore/json/schemaless-data-in-RDBMS storage. Any of those seem more reasonable than going meta-meta on an RDBMS. Is there a particular reason you're trying to create a custom schema for all data instead of making the data fit a schema that can represent schema-less data?

Comment: This indeed sounds as if `hstore`, `JSON` (or XML) would be a better fit for you. `hstore` is you only have key/value information. `JSON` if you have structured/hierarchical data. Whether or not JSON is suited depends heavily on what is hidden behind the little "*is then analyzed*" requirement.

Comment: @deceze unfortunately the columns are almost always different on a per client basis and there are new ones with each client.  I added my current solution thoughts.  Basically the custom client data becomes a blob either json,yml, or store it in some nosql db.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name json would work given the relatively small number of rows.  Analysis is some medium heavy stats stuff.  Besides your experience telling you that many tables are a terrible idea.  I was wondering if you could point to any particular problems associated with lots of tables.

Comment: Just for example, are you aware of the possibility of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model), and if so why is it not a solution?

Comment: @deceze my cursory understanding of EAV was incorrect, I'm looking further into it.

Comment: Thousands of tables is bad because it is a symptom of bad design. But if you can't restrain the clients to a certain schema then the battle is lost and you will suffer the consequences for the eternity :))

Comment: @deceze after looking further into EAV it would be an acceptable solution.  Though it's a bit of a waste with each client having dense clearly defined information, and a bit of a waste in having to pivot the data in from the client and out to the analysis.  But totally workable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One risk is that you have a rather untypical setup which is not tested and used by many other people. So you might be the first one to experience problems and the only one asking for a bugfix.

I do not think this will cause problems if you have 1000s of customers but you can never be sure how your solution scales to e.g. millions of customers. There might be cases where a sequential read will kill your performance.

On the other hand your solution gives very efficient data storage if each column is filled with data. By many factors better than EAV.

Comment: Ultimately I think this strikes at the heart of the problem.  There are too many unknown unknowns in a world of many tables and likely very few to have ventured there were I to go.

Answer (score 1):

There were many places in the older versions of PostgreSQL that would take N^2 time in the number of tables to do database dumps, restores from dumps, and upgrades with pg_upgrade.  This could become unbearable around 100,000 tables.  So while the system would run fine in normal operations, it would become essentially unmanageable in terms of maintenance.

Most of those cases have been fixed in 9.2 or 9.3, so if you do want to do this you should start out in version 9.3.